# Index on TIMESTAMP column not used when there is comparison in WHERE clause against that column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

Having two tables like:

```
FOO(ID, A, B, C, D, E, G(timestamp))
BAR(ID, X, Y, Z, FK_FOO_ID, W)
```

and having `index` such as:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_TEST ON FOO(G)
```

Following `DESCRIBE` query will **not** use created index:

```
DESC SELECT F.A, F.B, F.C, F.D, F.E,
  SUM(CASE WHEN B.X IN (0, 12) THEN B.Y ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'Something_1',
  SUM(CASE WHEN B.X IN (0, 12) THEN B.Z ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'Something_2',
  SUM(CASE WHEN B.X = 2 THEN B.Y ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'Something_3',
  SUM(CASE WHEN B.X = 2 THEN B.Z ELSE 0.00 END) AS 'Something_4'
FROM FOO AS F
INNER JOIN BAR AS B ON F.ID = B.FK_FOO_ID
WHERE
  (F.G > '2018-03-01 23:59:59' OR F.G IS NULL) AND
  B.W <= '2018-03-01 23:59:59' AND
  B.X IN (0, 2, 12)
GROUP BY
  F.A,
  F.B,
  F.C,
  F.D,
  F.E;
```

but with **removing** `F.G > '2018-03-01 23:59:59'` from `WHERE` clause, created index **will be** applied. Any ideas why? How to "force" MYSQL to use index on column `G` which is of type `TIMESTAMP`? Any ideas for better index to create with this type of `SELECT` query?

Comment: You can force it to use the index with the following syntax
SELECT <column> FROM <table> USE INDEX(<index>) WHERE ...

Comment: yes agree, but would really like to avoid that, that would be the last thing if i can not make it work in other way

Comment: @ Ivan Milasevic - It is not the best idea to force a index. the optimizer say witch index is to use for the fastest way. the optimizer do that on statistical data of the row. and you have more / other data in you columns they can use a other way (with/ without) index, BUT NOT IF YOU FORCE  a index. So change your query

Comment: Does it get better if you remove `OR F.G IS NULL` ?

Comment: Also, see if adding `INDEX(X,W)` to `B` helps.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer decides whether or not to use an index according to the statistics, meaning the frequency of different values in the column.

In your case when you remove the F.G > '2018-03-01 23:59:59' condition, the condition that's left is just to check if null, which is a more frequent value.

More than that, When checking for null it doesn't check the value itself in the column, but has a bit for each row that tells it if the value in the column is null or not. So that makes it even faster.

when you add the condition back it's probably faster for it to find the matching ID first and then to check if G matches.

It will also use the primary key because it needs to use it to get the values for

```
F.A, F.B, F.C, F.D, F.E,
```

If you really want it to use your index, you'll probably need to make it a covering one, meaning you need to add these columns to your index

Comment: tried with (ID, G) already, same story. I would completely agree with you if index would not be in use in a case when `F.G > '2018-03-01 23:59:59'` is removed

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. Corrected my answer.